How to configure turbo watch mode?
I'm maintaining a monorepo (which uses pnpm).
Packages are a mix of shared libraries, tools, Webpack 4 and Vite application.
Because the layer of dependencies is quite complex (up to 15 dependencies, recursively, for a project), I can't watch all dependencies in parallel. That's why I'm trying to implement turborepo's watch command for old application that cannot rebuild by themself when a dependency changes.
Basically, I have, for all my packages a build strict. I also have for my webpack 4 application a dev command. The serve command understand when a dependency output is rebuilt (but is not able to compile the dependency).
turbo.json declares dev task to depend on ^build:
{
    "$schema": "https://turbo.build/schema.json",
    "tasks": {
        "build": {
            "dependsOn": ["^build"],
            "outputs": ["dist/**"]
        },
        "dev": {
            "dependsOn": ["^build"],
            "persistent": true,
            "cache": false
        }
    }
}

So what I expect is to run turbo watch dev and have:

All dependencies to be build (taken from the cache if possible)
starts dev command on the wp project
rebuild a single dependency whenever its code changes.

Unfortunately, it does not works. I get some errors regarding dependency compilation (seems turbo tries to compile dependencies without respecting the build order).
On the other hand turbo build run without any issue. Adding --summary shows the dependency graph is correct.
What should I do? watch command help didn't help me to understand what I did wrong.
